# Passing variable to Runnable is null BEFORE the next line where it is made null

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Runnable class and a separate class where I am passing a variable into the Runnable (ArrayList). If I do not empty the array list (line 3 below) it runs as expected, however on emptying the arraylist after starting the thread it is empty in thread? The code execution should run as:

```
Line 1 - ArrayList -> full
Line 2 - Thread start and ArrayList is passed into the thread
Line 3 - ArrayList -> empty
```

Runnable:

```
public class RunnableDatabaseUpdater implements Runnable  {

    private Thread _t;
    private ArrayList<DatabaseQueueObject> _dbList;

    RunnableDatabaseUpdater(ArrayList<DatabaseQueueObject> databaseQueue) {
        _dbList = databaseQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread running..");

        for (DatabaseQueueObject f : _dbList) {
            System.out.println("Datbase query in queue from the thread: " + f.getdatabaseInteractionType() + ", query: " + f.getdatabaseQuery());
        }

        System.out.println("Thread DB queue exiting..");
    }

    public void start () {
        if (_t == null) {
            _t = new Thread (this);
            _t.start ();
        }
    }
}
```

Calling class:

```
    if(_masterDatabaseQueue.isEmpty()) return; // empty so return

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Starting database scheduled update..");

        RunnableDatabaseUpdater dbUpdater = new RunnableDatabaseUpdater(_masterDatabaseQueue);
        dbUpdater.start();

        // now the thread is running empty the queue so it may be used immediately for the next update cycle
        this._emptyDatabaseQueue();

    }
}
```

In the example above (how i want it to work) when checking via if(_dbList.isEmpty()) returns true.

Why is the thread taking an empty ArrayList before it is emptied? I have checked that the ArrayList contains what I expect before sending it to the new thread.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a synchronisation issue, using the Thread.join() removes this issue!